# Sitecore CLI 4.1.0-r00492 Login erroring "Endpoint belongs to different authority:"

Tags: sitecore-cli

I have installed a brand new, vanilla version of Sitecore 10.2, using Docker Desktop containers.

My Identity URL (which works) is https://xp0id.localhost.
My CM Url (which works) is https://xp0cm.localhost.

I can log into Sitecore with no problem.

I have installed the Sitecore CLI following the instructions [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/install-sitecore-command-line-interface.html).
[image]

I am trying to log into Sitecore and getting the following error message:

"Endpoint belongs to a different authority: [https://XP0id.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks"](https://XP0id.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks%22)
[image]

The openid-configuration appears correct:

```
{"issuer":"https://xp0id.localhost","jwks_uri":"https://XP0id.localhost/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks","authorization_endpoint":"https://XP0id.localhost/connect/authorize","token_endpoint":"https://XP0id.localhost/connect/token","userinfo_endpoint":"https://XP0id.localhost/connect/userinfo","end_session_endpoint":"https://XP0id.localhost/connect/endsession","check_session_iframe":"https://XP0id.localhost/connect/checksession","revocation_endpoint":"https://XP0id.localhost/connect/revocation","introspection_endpoint":"https://XP0id.localhost/connect/introspect","device_authorization_endpoint":"https://XP0id.localhost/connect/deviceauthorization","frontchannel_logout_supported":true,"frontchannel_logout_session_supported":true,"backchannel_logout_supported":true,"backchannel_logout_session_supported":true,"scopes_supported":["openid","profile","email","sitecore.profile","sitecore.profile.api","offline_access"],"claims_supported":["sub","name","family_name","given_name","middle_name","nickname","preferred_username","profile","picture","website","gender","birthdate","zoneinfo","locale","updated_at","email","email_verified","role","http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/isAdmin","http://www.sitecore.net/identity/claims/originalIssuer"],"grant_types_supported":["authorization_code","client_credentials","refresh_token","implicit","password","urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"],"response_types_supported":["code","token","id_token","id_token token","code id_token","code token","code id_token token"],"response_modes_supported":["form_post","query","fragment"],"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["client_secret_basic","client_secret_post","private_key_jwt"],"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256"],"subject_types_supported":["public"],"code_challenge_methods_supported":["plain","S256"],"request_parameter_supported":true}
```

I've validated the the ClientSecret is the same on both CM and ID server environment variables.

How do I get past this?

EDIT 1:
Chet requested in the comments that I add the variables for the IdentityServer host config. These are run as docker containers, and those variables are set via environment variables.

CM Environment Variables (not all, just the related ones):

> Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_SitecoreIdentity.Secret=vO1NgeC4l3DbbTm1pzh3DqelL8VHofYf6E6nu4AcqdJaEOmkgvPh5tKpy4Q0vXng
> Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Solr.Search=http://solr:8983/solr;solrCloud=true
> Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Web=Data Source=mssql;Initial
> Catalog=Sitecore.Web;User ID=sa;Password=Password12345
> Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_XConnect.Collection=http://xconnect
> Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Operations.Client=http://xconnect
> Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.MarketingAutomation.Reporting.Client=http://xconnect
> Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Processing.Pools=Data
> Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.pools;User ID=sa;P
> assword=Password12345
> Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Processing.Tasks=Data
> Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecore.Processing.tasks;User ID=sa;P
> assword=Password12345
> Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.Referencedata=Data Source=mssql;Initial
> Catalog=Sitecore.Referencedata;User ID=sa;Passwor d=Password12345
> Sitecore_ConnectionStrings_Xdb.ReferenceData.Client=http://xconnect
> Sitecore_Identity_Server_Authority=https://XP0id.localhost
> Sitecore_Identity_Server_CallbackAuthority=https://XP0cm.localhost
> Sitecore_Identity_Server_InternalAuthority=http://id
> Sitecore_Identity_Server_Require_Https=false

Identity Server Environment Vars:

> Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__CertificateRawDataPassword=7dkHdsNp40mZ
> Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__DefaultClient__AllowedCorsOrigins__AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1=https://XP0cm.localhost
> Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__Clients__PasswordClient__ClientSecrets__ClientSecret1=vO1NgeC4l3DbbTm1pzh3DqelL8VHofY
> f6E6nu4AcqdJaEOmkgvPh5tKpy4Q0vXng
> Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__PublicOrigin=https://XP0id.localhost
> Sitecore_Sitecore__IdentityServer__SitecoreMemberShipOptions__ConnectionString=Data
> Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=Sitecor e.Core;User
> ID=sa;Password=Password12345

EDIT 2:
Also adding content of file requested:
[image]

EDIT 3:
Here is the same file from the production folder:
[image]

EDIT 4:
Sitecore 10.2 Install Guide where Topology was suggested to be all caps.
I used "XP0" for my compose-init.
[image]

EDIT 5:
Trying different case:
[image]

Comment: The allowed clients are defined in the `Config\Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` file.  It would be helpful if you could share the contents of this file.  More detail here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-a-sitecore-instance-and-sitecore-identity-server.html

Comment: Sure, these are run as docker containers, so all of those variables are set as environment variables.   But yes, let me add those environment variables.s

Comment: Two things: I do see that your environment variables are showing the topology prefix in all caps ‘https://XP0’ but your examples are showing lowercase.  Probably not an issue, but thought I’d call it out.

Comment: Is there a space in one of the ID server environment variables? ‘AllowedCorsOriginsGroup1=https://XP0cm.lo calhost’

Comment: @ChetCheeto Thing 1: the prefix came in from the compose-init when I set up Sitecore.  I didn't specify URLs, so Sitecore used the default for these.  I'm going to add a snippet from the 10.2 Install Guide where it shows to use caps in topology.

Comment: @ChetCheeto Thing 2:  Not a space, that was a copy/paste error from terminal to stack exchange.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Just for giggles, do you get the same error if you use `--authority https://xp0id.localhost` in your CLI command?

Comment: Yeah, I tried different cases of all of the URL's.  No difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the comments questioned the casing of the topology.  In trying to figure this out, I decided to burn down the docker implementation and start over from scratch.

Instead of using `-Topology "XP0"`, I used `-Topology "xp0"`in the `compose-init` command when installing Sitecore.

This ended up fixing the issue with the Sitecore CLI login.

Comment: Kinda nice being able to tear down an environment and spin it back up in a few minutes :)